# Is it possible to change the model for an armature with animations present?

Tags: modeling, animation, armature

So i have made some animation with a character i made, and there are like 5 animations. Now i have added some details to it and i would like to update the model and use the new one and keep all the animation. Is it possible?

Basicly the position it's all the same, the new model has only a tail added to it (It's humanoid like goblin).

Can i use automatic weight somehow or reatribute all the wieght manually. And how can i keep the animation?

EDIT

[image]

As you can see on the image the are identical, the white one is the new one and it's the one i want to swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primary**

Yes it is possible.

Assuming you have done [no] custom weight painting.  You can simply achieve the initial starting base pose state, delete the old armature modifier, and parent the new armature with automatic weights.

Deleting the armature modifier of the mesh wont delete the animations of the armature.  Armature modifier is different than the armature itself.  The armature is referenced in the armature modifier.  You can even parent the armature to 2 or more meshes.

To achieve a base position you can clear all the rotations and positions temporarily.  There are menu options such as [clear rotation] for bones of an armature. Consider having  frame 0 for that case.  You can render frames 1 to N which does not include frame 0.

If you are planning to replace one mesh entirely with the new mesh simply achieve your base position and parent the armature to the new mesh. Test.  Then delete your old mesh.  You may want to save multiple copies of your Blender file.  Blender allows you do make any mesh invisible to view or render which may be convenient in your case.

If you have done custom weight painting.  Just go into weight paint mode and paint the weight for the new bones and test.

**Secondary**

You picture appears to introduce a new question.  If you have two meshes you can join them with a menu selection [Join Meshes].  Makes sure you select the dominant mesh last.

If the meshes are two different objects you do not even need to join them.  The single armature can be the target of more than one armature modifier on two different meshes as stated above.

Comment: But how do i move the animations? That's the most important part, weight painting even manually is easy, but idk how to move animations

Comment: Also, frame 0 isn't the same as the base position. The location change aswell.

Comment: Move what dimension? Time dimension?  Location XYZ dimension?

Comment: If i select HP_Obj (see on the image) It moves to where the armature starting pose is, and it's higher. To get the view i have on the picture i had to click on Armature.001 (see image). So idk how i have ot merge meshes.

Comment: Oh wow, so idk if you mean that, but i deleted every vertex group on my old model, then parented the new one to the armature and set automatic weight. And it worked. Deem thanks :)

Comment: Armatures are flexible in use when you are practiced with them.  Whether you delete vertex groups or not is not essential.  You can remove the armature modifier as well.  Eventually you might delete the old mesh object .